# FAQ about notability shouldn't talk about the league of justice

Tags: discussion, about-faq

The FAQ on notability, [FAQ: Must all questions be notable?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/864/faq-must-all-questions-be-notable) , shouldn't talk about the league of justice or superheroes.

We shouldn't assume that people using Skeptics.SE use, or even care, about other Stack Exchange sites, so long as their question is on-topic for this site.

Also, talking about superheroes is a distraction, when all I want to do is provide a link where people can understand that claims ought to be notable and referenced (for example, to https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7390/electromagnetic-field-alters-directional-path-of-light ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your middle sentence appears to be irrelevant. Many Skeptics users will have experience of other SE sites (especially SO, the grand-daddy of them all). It is important to explain why the 'topic' of Skeptics is defined slightly differently from others. We do other explanations of why SE sites in general are different from other paradigms users are likely to have encountered, such as forum threads.

I believe there is nothing wrong with using superhero analogies to explain this. I'm not a comic fan, but the point is made.