# When is it appropriate to migrate a question to another site?

Tags: discussion, proposed-faq

Our site allows questions about [notable claims](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1491/what-is-notability-and-how-should-we-enforce-it) on almost any topic. It is therefore unsurprising that we need to have a well specified migration policy.

What are the conditions under which we should migrate questions to other sites?

Answer (score 3):

### Questions should be off-topic

Example of off-topic questions are questions which are not about a notable claim, or not about a claim at all. Direct questions about a field of science, for example: "How do lightnings work?". We also don't allow *research-level* questions, for example: "What are the consequences of faster-than-light neutrinos?"

### The other site must accept it

Although it is not required by the software, it is common practice among moderators to *ask for permission* before transferring a question. It is also useful, because questions might need to be retagged or edited to fit better in their new home.

### The poster must not refuse the migration

The migration needs to be proposed to the author by the community or a moderator. This should be done concurrently to a *close vote*, as it should only be done on off-topic questions. If the author accepts then the question can be migrated to its new home, if the author refuses it will be closed (or stay closed).

#### Abandoned questions

Abandoned questions can be migrated without the author's permission.

#### Questions that are on-topic

Sometimes questions are on topic, but possibly better served somewhere else. In this case, it's only appropriate to migrate with the author's consent.

Comment: Downvoters! please explain your votes so we can fix this answer! :-)

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but are you sure about asking the poster for permission? If you as a moderator (plus those who voted to migrate) think it's clearly better for another site (giving the other requirements for fulfilled), then it's alright to migrate it even if the OP refuses. Also because they might refuse not for serious reasons.

Comment: @Alenanno once a question is closed, then I don't see the problem in *not* migrating. Some users have explicitly asked not to migrate (for example because they want reference-backed answers) and would prefer to fix their question instead.

Comment: Ok, but I was taking into account those users that would refuse "just because", if you know what I mean. :)

Comment: If they refuse "just because", then their question will stay closed (unless they convince the community to reopen) instead of migrated. Migration is an opportunity for the users to get their off topic question actually answered, if they refuse... too bad :-)

Comment: +1 for not migrating without permission. Users who refuse to the migration either will want to fix their question, or won't in which case it doesn't matter so much.