# Let's define "a large number of people"

Tags: discussion, support

We have [a policy that states](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2506/what-is-a-notable-claim/2507#2507)

> The idea here is that once a large number of people are exposed to the claim, it is of general interest to validate the claim and either confirm or refute it.

I have a [separate question asking what kind of sources](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5033/3835) can satisfy "a large number of people". Here I want to ask what is a "large number".

We have one user which has told me in chat,

> The term large number isn't defined anywhere and depending on context 50,000 can be small or large

I would like to make our policy clear enough such that 50,000 people being exposed to a claim is always "large enough" to be notable. I would be willing to go down too. But I think we can set an objective floor for "large number" to stop some of the malicious trolling on this site.

Comment: A large number of people is going to vary depending upon the context. You keep trying to twist my words to make them mean what you want them to.

Comment: It is not possible to set an objective number for something that is inherently subjective. We could indeed stop some of the malicious trolling on this site if we stopped trying to be rules-lawyers and instead think coherently about the purpose, the intent, and the context of the site.

Comment: Why is it "inherently subjective" why would some claims be notable with 50,000 non-celebrities exposed to them and other claims not be notable with 50,000 non-celebrities exposed to them?

Comment: This is a duplicate of a [2017 question](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1660/how-about-a-firm-minimum-threshold-for-notability), but this is an area where community standards might have shifted in the last 7 years, so I haven't close it.

Comment: @Oddthinking what is your feeling about whether or not this should be subjective? I'm strongly opposed to this notion. People should be reasonably confident a question is on topic based on our scope before they ask. And if we have a notion of notability that entirely subjective it eliminates that confidence and puts new users in conflict with people that have a different subjective interpretation. Also generally policy should aim for objectivity.

Comment: It's a bizarre oversight that the questions "Are bananas 99% water?" and "Are oranges 99% water?" currently have two potentially different standards for notability.

Comment: @Oddthinking That question and answer are actually from 2012 and it was just last edited in 2017.

Comment: If you feel that it should not be objective I would suggest writing an answer to this question and explain why you think there should be a set number for what is notable.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: on a mobile device, so am keeping it brief. I have written before that I am against having a specific number. The 2012 answer (Thanks for the correction, JoeW) was all I could find (without a decent screen and keyboard). Ultimately, the issue is "Do we want to spend our limited resources on answering/editing/evaluating this question?" and that is hard to objectively determine.

Comment: @Oddthinking I have laid out my argument below.

Answer (score -2):

## Argument for Objectivity

### Subjectivity is befuddling, and exclusionary

The site's [Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct) says the mission is to "foster collaboration within a safe and **welcoming community rooted in kindness, cooperation and mutual respect**."

- **We don't prepare users for what they're getting into:** An ideal new users reads our [Help Pages on Asking a Question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This page makes no mention that, topicality aside, questions may otherwise be not-welcome here if they fail an arbitrary "notability" guideline. Lacking this defeats the purpose of the network in providing it. If you click through the only mention of notability on our Help page you find a meta post which has in its answer a link to our policy on notability which says only,

  > The idea here is that once a large number of people are exposed to the claim, it is of general interest to validate the claim and either confirm or refute it.

  **That I'm here arguing this is because a question was closed which had [60,000 people sign a petition on change.org](https://www.change.org/p/invoke-article-6-and-expel-the-us-from-the-united-nations).** This is clear evidence of even the most experienced users not knowing what a "large number of people are exposed to the claim" mean, and experienced moderators arguing that 60,000 people exposed is insufficient under the terms of our policy.
- **Even if we did, what we're forcing users into is unwelcoming:** We're setting up new users for a conflict when we demand notability and notability can not be known before submission. Even if we told users, regardless of topicality, "all questions may closed if they're deemed unnnotable and there is no defense to this charge" we're only disclosing at that point that we're a fairly unkind community. While we can't fault users regardless, they're like to fault us if they take time to submit a well crafted question that is otherwise on topic, and it fails for a lack of notability.
- **None of this required:** From my perspective, it's not clear why we want this. Consider this,

  - Are all apples are made of titanium?
  - Are all oranges are made of titanium?

  Why should these two questions have a different criteria for notability? If 5,000 retweets on one substantiates a claim to notability, why would that ever not be sufficient for another? We also don't need to specify a ceiling for notability. For example, it may be such that some claims are less likely to be viewed then others: "Is fluoride more deadly than uranium when injected", is likely to be less trafficked then any claim about a president. But, we can still provide guidance. We can still say **"Something is notable if it has gone viral. For our purposes viral is a single post with has 5,000 retweets+favorites, signatures on a petition, or likes on Facebook."**
- **The effect on mod culture is toxic.** Lacking guidance, moderators feel (and I can provide direct evidence for this) that they're not enforcing policy, but instead using a more heavy downvote. This goes against the design of this site: a downvote is to show you dislike the question or answer and requires no justification. A vote-to-close and vote-to-delete is a tool for enforcement of policy. You can downvote a question you feel is too esoteric and otherwise a poor question. **It is wrong to use a vote-to-close as a heavier downvote for a more experienced user**.
- **The effect on the community is toxic.** Rules like this are likely to be *more* enforced against people you do not agree with, dislike, or don't know. This is not the way a community should be run. Subjective rules lead to subjective enforcement which prejudices established people. Take for instance me, I filed a TOS violation report for this rule because this is how I *feel* it was used. I don't think StackExchange wants to deal with this, but who knows.
- **Subjective policy sets up mods to fight.**  Do you really want to create an environment where mods are voting to close and open questions based on their preference for a definition of "notability"? This shouldn't be a fight on a question; this should be a conversation on meta.
- **No mutual respect nor cooperation between mods and users** when we tell our users that any submission of a question must be done in ignorance to whether or nor the question is notable, and we tell our mods they can vote-to-close a question for a lack of notability without specifying what is required to make the question notable, we are **NOT** creating a community that fosters cooperation and mutual respect.

Comment: When the question was closed it didn't have 60,000 signatures, you shouldn't keep inflating the number based on changes that happen after the question was closed and deleted.

Comment: @JoeW Are you stating that you no longer feel that the question should be closed because it's crossed your threshold for notability? If so, I would like you to cast a vote to reopen **before** you make the argument that the difference between the amount of signatures then and now is material.

Comment: Again you are twisting my words and I never said or implied that. I only stated you keep changing the number of people who signed that online petition as it grows instead of focusing on the number when it was asked, closed and deleted.

Comment: @JoeW yes, i'm simply using the change.org petition which is in my bookmarks, rather than trying to figure out what i said first, but just to be clear we agree it's not material here, right? I'm talking about your close vote and regardless of 30,000 or 60,000, it's not material to you. You don't feel a "large number of people have been exposed to the claim"

Comment: None of that justifies keeping increasing the number as it just makes it seems like you are trying to change the situation to change things.

Comment: @JoeW I'm not changing the situation, your vote to close still stands. If I was changing the situation, you'd have a point. It's simple. Whether 30,000 or 60,000 your vote to close, remains. I'll use the 60,000 number to state my point, just because I'm morally opposed to changing anything that's not material to the claim. Especially when for someone who I've politely asked to not talk to me ever again, and who has asked the same of me!

Comment: Your claim about the number of votes on the online petition is different then when the question was asked, closed and deleted and that is the issue.

Comment: @JoeW An issue must be material. It's not material.

Comment: I disagree with your statement as you keep changing the numbers that you are using to make your claims that it is a notable claim. Those numbers should match what it was when you asked the question and not keep changing as the change and you think they make your question better.

Comment: Again, we disagree. You've already downvoted. Please stop talking to me (or commenting on my answer).

Comment: As I have stated in another question, at this point I am just responding to you. If you keep trying twist my words I will keep responding, if you stop trying to twist my words I will stop responding.

Comment: I have never twisted your words. You told me _"I never said or implied that [I would **NOT** have voted to close with 60,000 signatures]"_. That makes it immaterial, so I'm not changing it. Now, again, please stop commenting on my answer.

Comment: Again, you did as you said " Are you stating that you no longer feel that the question should be closed because it's crossed your threshold for notability?". All I stated in my comment was that the number of votes at the time your question was asked was not the same as you stated it in this answer which is misleading about what happened.

Comment: That's a question. Is your argument that I "twisted your words" by asking you a question?

Comment: Yes, you implied that my vote would change based on this when I made no suggestion that I would change my vote based on the new numbers.

Comment: @JoeW No, I never implied that. I asked you a question. If your vote _would_ have changed then you would have a material argument, and I would have to update my answer. Both with a new number, and with the new information you've provided. But you haven't said that any of this actually matters, except to raise a question which you clearly believe has some kind of philosophical merit, but we're in disagreement. Please stop commenting on my answer.

Comment: I disagree with your assertion, I didn't make any suggestion that my vote was dependent on the number of votes in your original question  or your new misleading answer but you decided to twist my statement about your change in the numbers to be related to my close vote. Also as your answer is deleted and I don't have the privilege to cast delete or undelete votes my vote doesn't matter.

Comment: _"I didn't make any suggestion that my vote was dependent on the number of votes in your original question"_ **I never said you made that suggestion.** What are you refuting? I asked you a question: _"Are you stating that you no longer feel that the question should be closed because it's crossed your threshold for notability?"_ Please stop commenting on my answer.

Comment: That is how I took your response to my comment stating the issue with you changing the numbers each time you bring this up. As I stated before I am only responding to your replies to me.

Comment: @JoeW so what you're saying is that you're entitled to the last word, on my answer?