# Is question on whether a public belief is true or false is on topic?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is notability and how should we enforce it?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1491/what-is-notability-and-how-should-we-enforce-it)

Seems like I am not getting it properly. All the good questions, I have seen here, ask about the possibility of some claims (generally found on internet) with the links attached. So it is easy to understand and discuss on the claim and hence getting a good answer (resulting in a no. of up-votes to the question!). The questions I have till now asked about the possibility of claims generally heard in public over here in India. As India is a diverse country [there are lots and lots of culture, cast, creed and religion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culture_of_India). So a lot of different public beliefs come to hear. Some of them sound strange. So if I ask question regarding those public beliefs I cant post any link to support my claim. I cant say it stereotype thought or common belief either, because it may seem *strange* to people outside! So how should I present these questions or frame its language so that I can convince it is not likely that I have not done any research, but its a *too localized* belief to be found any evidence on the internet? I guess the questions I posted had no links attached with it and that is why people here is not getting its relevance and resulting some down-votes to my questions; hence I asked this question to be clarified.

Comment: Can you give a couple of examples? It's very hard to give a general answer here, imo.

Comment: I have asked only 3 questions. 2 of them: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14325/does-drinking-of-coconut-water-harm-sperm-production and http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/13792/can-tummo-yoga-practitioners-withstand-extreme-cold are based on popular beliefs.The coconut water I heard in rural area of West Bengal and My question on Indian Yoga was edited to Tummo Yoga(Thanks to _Oddthinking_ for that as the aim of the question is still same) which is also a popular belief. But at least we cant find any relevant discussion on 1st claim over the internet!

Comment: They seem both perfectly on topic to me...

Comment: Then please give a general answer as to whether they are on topic or not and that every claim can not be supported by links only. There can be stereotype thoughts which also can be place and people specific.

Comment: We already have a [general answer](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1491/what-is-notability-and-how-should-we-enforce-it); both your questions though, do have links (!?) -- I am not quite sure what you want me to answer...

Comment: ... **sic transit gloria mundi** ("worldly things are fleeting") ...

Comment: @Sklivvz, This is indeed a general answer! Thanks for citing! You can close it now as duplicate!

Comment: @Carlo_R., what does your comment mean? I believe its a famous quote!