# What do I need to do to get this question reopened?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

[This question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14522/does-drinking-water-help-heal-sickness) of mine was recently closed.

I assume it was closed resulting from

> Shouldn't this be closed unless someone can provide a reference to a notable claim that states drinking extra water aids healing even when dehydration is not an issue? – RedGrittyBrick 2 days ago

It had been my assumption most people have heard doctors give that advice - even in situations where the illness has no additional risk of dehydration. This was why I asked this question (to determine whether or not this advice had any basis).

What do I need to change in order to make the question constructive for Skeptics?

Answer (score 1):

Please read:

- [FAQ: Welcome to New Users](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users)
- [FAQ: Must all questions be notable?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/864/faq-must-all-questions-be-notable)
- [How should we enforce notability?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1491/what-is-notability-and-how-should-we-enforce-it)

If it is true that many doctors advise to drink plenty of fluids even when there is no risk for dehydration, then it should be easy to find them saying so "on record" on the internet.