# Would the question "Did Einstein actually say X?" be on-topic here?

Tags: discussion

Would it be on-topic to ask here:

> Did Einstein actually say:
>
> "Make everything as simple as possible, but no simpler?"

By my reading of the FAQ, I would think not.  Skeptiks [is about](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Skeptics Stack Exchange is for challenging unreferenced notable
>   claims, pseudoscience and biased results.

But this question is not about challenging the claim that it is best to make everything as simple as possible -- only that Einstein claimed that it was.

So, is this question on-topic here?

Note:  I'm aware that there are some questions on Skeptics which ask very similar questions about the attribution of a particular quote, and many of those were well-upvoted and not closed.  However, since StackExchange is not a perfect model of it's own policies (as commonly seen on StackOverflow), that does not mean those questions are on-topic.

Answer (score 6):

It's accepted as on-topic: by convention, because [there are many similar questions](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quotes).

Pretty well any question of the following form is on-topic here:

> [Reference to notable claim] says, "[quote the claim]". Is that claim true?

So if you can find a 'notable' claim that Einstein said that, you are allowed to question whether that claim is true.

[Sometimes you don't even need to find a reference](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2499/2703), if the claim is commonly accepted to be notable.

The original purpose of the web site might have been science, pseudo-science, perhaps advertising; but it has since strayed far, far into other topics (e.g. history, journalism, and quotes like these).