# Is asking a question on the authenticity of a quote off topic?

Tags: discussion

I came across a quote during my research, the source of which was not clear. I am pretty sure that the claim is well established, yet I am more interested if a certain personality ever stated a statement surrounding the claim.

Now, to me it is two different things

1. The Claim itself that is well established.
2. A Statement on a claim, that was made at a time when the claim was probably not well established (I may be wrong here, but that what I found).

It seems the question was not well received. People suggested that the question is trying `publicize the claim` and considering the Claim is well established, it is fruitless to establish if a certain personal ever stated saying the same.

So, if a claim is well established, being skeptical about a certain individuals statement on that particular claim, offtopic?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're referring to this question:

[Did political analyst, Larry Sabato ever say "The higher the education level, the more likely they are to vote Democratic."?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/30632/did-political-analyst-larry-sabato-ever-say-the-higher-the-education-level-th)

As you see, the question is not put on hold or closed as off-topic and you've got two answers. Your question has also has a rate of +2, which is not bad.

Asking about the authenticity of any quote is on-topic as you see [here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quotes); there are 122 questions.

However, there are many cases where the community dislikes the question, maybe because sometimes it doesn't really matter whether X said Y or maybe because the OP already found evidence while asking the question.

There could many reasons why your question was not well received and one reason has been explained by [Oddthinking](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/30632/did-political-analyst-larry-sabato-ever-say-the-higher-the-education-level-th#comment115547_30632):

> I don't know why it was downvoted, but I wonder if it is because there is little reason for doubt here. The idea that he said it is a fairly prosaic claim. The Politifact article discusses how they actually asked Sabato to substantiate the quote, and he did so, in a way that they conclude is "Mostly True". Why wouldn't you provisionally accept this rather prosaic claim as true, given the substantial evidence you've already discovered?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is Yes, it is on-topic.

See this question for the reasoning:

> [Would the question "Did Einstein actually say X?" be on-topic here?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2595/would-the-question-did-einstein-actually-say-x-be-on-topic-here)

I've expressed my boredom of them, and tried to rally to community to say they are no longer welcome - See this meta-question:

> [Should we limit [quote] questions?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3192/should-we-limit-quote-questions)

The community clearly responded that they are okay.