# What can we do to encourage users to provide answers for the questions?

Tags: discussion

In the first page there are only 2 questions of 15 questions supported by answers! I see there are not many answers in the other pages too. What is the reason?

- Bad questions?
- Difficult questions?
- Closed questions?
- Fear of downvotes?
- Not having enough experts in different field studies here unless a huge number of programmers and software experts?
- Tending to provide wiki answers and when there is no wiki answer everything ends?
- Mod's trend in accepting only wiki answers and stopping users to provide more creative answers associated with the other sources?
- Not having enough experts to recognize which answer is appropriate or not?

All or some of above or even more reasons can cause such passiveness in answering the questions.

What can we do to improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Titles should me more specific and self explanatory.

Comment: Agree! Good point! :)

Comment: Yes, agree. However it is not simple. Consider this case: "Does Yasuhiro Kubo own the world record for Banzai Sky diving?", yes here title is selfexplanatory because question is basic. But, now consider "Does a car with a hybrid engine and Lithium batteries pollute more than a car with conventional technology?" How can you reduce that complexity contextually giving the sense of the question? -1, anyway.

Comment: @Carlo_R It is obvious that in such cases titles may go long.It is simply logical that titles should be small as possible.The meaning behind my words lies in the fact that unnecessary words should not be included so long as they are necessary.

Answer (score 4):

You can put [bounties](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty) on questions for this purpose.

The basic problem is that answering questions here is hard by design, and sometimes people need encouragement - a bounty would help in that case.

Other times, there's just not enough information on the internet - not every experiment or claim has been tried... in which case, having no answer is fine.

Finally, some questions are simply badly posed, and they discourage people from answering.

I would like to encourage people to read here on meta what [constitutes a good question](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1346/96), so questions that don't have enough love can be improved and then answered.

Comment: +1 nice advices! :)

Comment: @PersianCat Regarding Sklivvz's "finally" part, sometimes it's very difficult to tell what is being asked.  Either from the part of the reader, or even the part of the asker.  In many cases this is because english is not the first language, and that may inhibit communication.  Maybe asking folks to help out in clarifying a question and intent could get more attention to it.

Comment: @LarianLeQuella Agree! If English speakers and natives try to edit or suggest edits (without changing the main matter) you can find better answers and help non English speakers to correct themselves too. In a world which all of us have to communicate in English it needs more cooperation to understand each other ideas and sentences better. You spend time and tolerance to edit us and we spend time and tolerance to communicate with you in a language which is not our mother tongue. There is no other way for an international cyber network.

Comment: Yes, I agree with Sklivvz on the bounty argument and I experienced a lot of bounty questions with a grave losting of rep-points. However language, as LeQuella said, is really the more important problem. To answer on Skeptics needs a perfect English padronance, otherwise you cannot exprime the difficult concept you have to exprime in order to post answers capable of being upvoted. Furthermore, I recently observed a trend of questions too localised on bio-chemical problems, with the conseguence that a lot of engineer and physicyan (phisicist? bo!) tend to go away.

Answer (score -1):

I used to answer questions here on skeptics, but the community was too critical of well supported answers coming from newer members. That is why I deleted those answers and refused to answer questions on this stackexchange site. Others aren't so bad, e.g. physics.se