# FAQ updated: request for comment

Tags: discussion, about-faq, new-users

I've updated our [FAQ](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq) to include a link to our "[Must all answers be referenced?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5)" post and our "[Welcome to New Users](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1505)" post.

In practice this

> **Skeptics - Stack Exchange** is for challenging [unreferenced notable claims](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/864/when-in-doubt-ask-for-a-citation), pseudoscience and biased results. Skeptics is about *applying* skepticism — it is for researching the evidence behind claims you encounter. It is *not* for speculation, philosophical discussions or investigating original claims.

has become this

> **Skeptics - Stack Exchange** is for challenging [unreferenced notable claims](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/864/when-in-doubt-ask-for-a-citation), pseudoscience and biased results.
>
> Skeptics is about *applying* skepticism — it is for [researching the evidence](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5) behind claims you encounter. It is *not* for speculation, philosophical discussions or investigating original claims.
>
> *New users* (even users familiar with the StackExchange format) *should read our [introduction to the site](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) before posting.*

This is justified by the amount of extra work that the community is experiencing to direct new users to these pages.

Please upvote/downvote/comment below. :-)

Comment: `Please downvote/upvote/comment below. :-)` would be more profitable