# No notable claim for the Polysporin question

Tags: discussion

In regards to the question: [Does Polysporin have advantages over soap](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2972/does-polysporin-have-advantages-over-soap)

It doesn't contain a notable claim.

The asker says "Some highly regarded sources" but it only provides one source. The chosen quote from that source is:

> Soap can irritate the wound, so try to keep it out of the actual
>   wound.

As though soap is being discouraged in place of Polysporin. But this is incorrect. In the same article it says:

> Thorough cleaning reduces the risk of infection and tetanus. To clean
>   the area around the wound, use soap and a washcloth.

So there is actually no source for the claim that Polysporin is either better than soap or should be used instead of soap.

The question is also asked: "Does Polysporin have anti-bacterial or other properties that are not found in soap".

Searching for the individual contents provided by the asker and also linked from the product website, you can find many reliable sources that say these ingredients have confirmed anti-bacterial properties. So there is nothing to say here.

I suggest this question be closed as not a real question as there isn't an actual notable claim.

Comment: @Sklivvz - Do any of the mods want to comment on this? Just trying to help to tidy some of the older unanswered questions up.

Answer (score 1):

I've closed the question.

Please note:

- The question was asked *before* our [standards on notability has been established](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/864/faq-must-all-questions-be-notable).
- I don't believe we have ever officially decided what to do with old questions and answers that have been "grandfathered" in from before our community standards were established. Occasionally, they will be brought to a mod's attention (like this one) and dealt with individually. There's been no systematic effort to ensure that they are all good.
- @Pericles316's answer here seems to have been mislocated. If it answered the question, I probably would have left the question open, but it seems to be about whether polysporin cures eczema, rather than whether it avoids irritating broken skin more than soap.

Answer (score 0):

No, since both soap and Polysporin does not have the necessary research proven ingredients to treat or cure eczema (atopic dermatitis).

> Treatments for AD have been non-specific, and serious adverse effects are possible. Treatments include creams and petroleum jelly (to help improve the skin’s protective barrier); antihistamines; drugs that suppress the whole immune system, such as prednisone (a steroid) or cyclosporine; and other topical treatments, including tacrolimus (an immunomodulator), and phototherapy (light treatment).

Polysporin [products](http://www.polysporin.ca/eczema) claim that it does not contribute to further irritation which is one of the symptoms of [eczema](https://nationaleczema.org/research/eczema-prevalence/). However, the Eczema Essentials products are not found in [NLM](https://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/drugInfo.cfm?setid=dd7aceb6-0666-4059-b2a9-8e7fe5f3f0ac) website except in ointment and powder form.

> Eczema is the common name for atopic dermatitis, a non-contagious skin condition that affects infants, children, and adults alike. In eczema, skin cannot hold onto moisture and can become dry and tight. Symptoms include skin itching, swelling and irritation. And if you can't keep from scratching, itchy skin can be damaged and become vulnerable to infection. Though there is no cure for eczema, you can help manage it through a daily skin care routine that focuses on gentle cleansing and replenishing moisture.

Dr. Sandy Skotnicki, Dermatologist and Medical Director at Bay Dermatology Centre recommends fragrance-free, non-foaming soap for eczema patients for reducing [symptoms](http://www.canadianliving.com/style/beauty/an_itch_you_cant_scratch_the_lowdown_on_eczema.php) of irritation.

> For others, eczema flares up because of irritation. When it comes to irritants, Dr. Skotnicki isn’t afraid to name names: “Cleansers, too much soap and all the stuff we put on our skin,” often formulated with fragrance, can result in angry, reactive and sensitized skin.

Comment: ...............? Maybe you meant to post this as an answer to the question?

Comment: @George Chalhoub-yes ur right!