# Should this question have been edited to provide positive spin?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question [here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/44479/is-this-photo-showing-a-woman-posing-in-the-nude-before-teenagers-real) which was edited by User DJ Clayworth to give the question a more positive spin. I edited to a more neutral spin, but he insists on leaving the positive spin version there.

As the OP, although my political viewpoints are irrelevant to the question, I do not want my question to imply a positive view on it. Furthermore, in the course of discussion, I was accused of imposing my viewpoint on others, while it should be evident that Dj Clayworth's viewpoint was imposed on me, as he insisted on changing it to a version more acceptable to him

As the OP, can I insist on leaving the unedited version in its place, and users can downvote as they see fit?

Comment: Relevant: https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2446/should-questions-try-to-be-unbiased and https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1203/faq-should-questions-be-asked-with-an-impartial-tone

Answer (score 10):

Looking at the [revisions](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/posts/44479/revisions).

Your original version:

> Is this photo showing a women flashing herself to schoolchildren real?

Your revised version:

> Is this photo showing a woman exposing herself in the nude before teenagers real?

Both of these are editorializing, using non-neutral terms:  exposing; flashing.  These have negative connotations.

The DJ Clayworth version:

> Is this photo showing a woman posing in the nude before teenagers real?

This uses a neutral term, posing.

Now, whether you, as the original poster, should have the right to use non-neutral terms in this context, I don't have a particularly strong opinion.  But your characterization of your terms versus the revised term is clearly incorrect.  You are using negative terms and the revised term is more neutral.

If you really dislike the term "posing", you might consider "standing" or simply removing that word.

> Is this photo of a nude woman in front of teenagers real?

Or

> Is this photo of teenagers looking at a nude woman real?

Comment: 'standing'  seems to me a perfectly acceptable neutral term of anyone thinks that 'posing' is worrier to positive or contains connotations inputting motivation or intent.

Comment: Posing implies it ewas expected. From the pictures it seems unexpected. So it is also inaccurate, besides for editorializing on someone else's question.

Comment: Switched to "Standing" as in @PhillS suggestion.

Comment: I just wanted to say that I am very happy with this revised version.

Comment: @TheAsh "editorializing" is what you did, using loaded terms to portray the incident as you perceived it - effectively writing [an editorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Editorial). What DJClayworth did your post was "editing".

Comment: @AaronF, I used the words most Americans would. Very few would call it "posing" or "art". As the OP, I have the right to do that.

Comment: @TheAsh and by posting it under CC-BY-SA everyone else has the right to change it.

Comment: But did anyone have the manners to ask? Does anyone have the sense to not give a damn?