# What is unclear about my question?

Tags: discussion

So, my question got put on hold (again), because it's unclear what I'm asking. Thanks for closing my question without providing any commentary whatsoever, so I have no idea what's wrong with this and I can't even improve question, despite my good will.

I'm talking about [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/30159/are-mass-bred-chicken-fed-with-hormones-or-other-substances-that-when-you-eat-t).  I rephrased it once, and it got re-opened - so I thought that now it was clear what my question is, but seems that I'm wrong.

So, what is unclear?

Answer (score 2):

thank you for asking in Meta.  Overall I don't think your question is unsalvageable, however I felt that it needed more attention than it had been provided.

First of all, a huge red flag on any question is "my friend told me".  [Normally we want a question to be notable to a certain degree](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/864/faq-must-all-questions-be-notable).  On this particular topic, I think notability would be a requirement.

Then you limit it to Poland.  Does chemistry or chicken biology work differently in Poland?  I think that particular added detail could cause some confusion, and also make the question more difficult to answer.

What specifically is the claim in "*presumably chicken are fed with hormones which can be unhealthy*"? That chickens are fed with hormones? That this is unhealthy? That it's unhealthy to whom (people or the chickens)?

You then go on to state "*as well as the meat could contain some added chemicals*".  What chemicals?  Water is a chemical that is quite often added in food processing. Is that what you are concerned about?

Are you maybe asking about [organic](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/search?q=organic) chicken farming?

Again, I think there is potential merit in this question, but in just three lines of text (on my screen), I was left with more questions as to what you were really skeptical about than anything.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've asked him to limit to a country, because there are different laws governing how meat can be treated.

Comment: Thanks for answer. At least now it's clearer. I'll thin about it, and maybe do some research and edit the question. Thanks!

Comment: @Sklivvz - FWIW, health/food related laws aren't necessarily science based. Witness current Russian snit over destroying "unsafe" Western food imports.