# Should information about the notability of a claimant/claim not be put in comments?

Tags: discussion, notability, comments

If someone questions the notability of a claim, or the claimant, and someone else wishes to assert the notability of the claim/claimant, should they avoid adding a comment, and instead edit the question?

In the question [Does Female Circumcision reduce urinary tract infections?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/38232/does-female-circumcision-reduce-urinary-tract-infections) , the OP provided information about the notability of the claimant in a comment (I think he indicated that the author of the quoted claim was notable, and had an English-language Wikipedia article about the author). However, the comment has since been deleted, and a user is currently questioning the notability of the claim. Should the OP have provided the information about the claimant in the question instead?

I understand that claims have to be notable, but I am concerned that providing too much information about the notability of a claim may be distracting.

Note: I'm not saying that the person who deleted the comment is the same person who is questioning the notability of the claim.

Comment: I have recently edited the question. I hope this clears up the misunderstanding about notability. I am hesitant to answer this question until it is clear it has, so we aren't discussing the same thing in two places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there was some honest mistake in there.

Our notability policy *requires* fixing the question if notability is disputed:

> If one person shows up, searches for evidence that the claim is notable, and then disputes the [notability of the] claim (leaves a comment, or flags for moderator attention) - then it's the responsibility of the asker (or your friendly neighborhood editor) to dig up a real, verifiable source.

-[FAQ: Must all questions be notable?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/864/faq-must-all-questions-be-notable)

Clearly this was not done. Clarifications were left in comments. Comments were deleted. A question whose notability was in doubt was not originally fixed.

All is sorted now, though.