# Change link in 'Notable claim' off topic close reason?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, off-topic

The first off-topic close reason has a link titled *unreferenced notable claims* pointing to [FAQ: Must all questions be notable?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/864/faq-must-all-questions-be-notable):

[image]

Shouldn't the link text be *notable claims*? The way it is formatted now suggests that *unreferenced* would not apply to 'pseudoscience and biased results'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done

Thanks for the suggestion (and thanks @Sklivvz for doing the work).