# How specific do claims have to be?

Tags: discussion

I recently posted a [question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/40461/does-saying-sorry-after-an-accident-count-as-legal-admission-of-fault) that references what I believe to be a commonly held belief based on numerous variations of it that I've heard people throughout the US and Western Europe make. Because it's often spoken and slightly varies (car accidents, medical malpractice, personal injury, etc.), I tried to distil the essence of the claim (don't admit fault or you might be legally liable) and ask if there's any truth to it.

I realize this can be potentially broad as the validity might vary by legal jurisdiction. But I still think it's the only way to handle claims that spread mostly through word of mouth instead of by writing.

A couple people in the comments thought I needed to cite a specific version of the claim to establish notability though.

How specific do claims have to be? Can I reference a cluster of very similar claims that spread through word-of-mouth or must I pick a single example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FAQ: Must all questions be notable?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/864/faq-must-all-questions-be-notable)

Comment: Possibly. The question purposes that common knowledge claims might get to slide unless someone challenges the notability. But even then, it's not clear that that part of the question was accepted and it's also possible to establish notability without asking a single specific question (you could cite several high profile versions that are all similar, for example).