# The first link on this help page needs to be fixed

Tags: support, bug

The first link on this help page needs to be fixed:
https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

It links to:
https://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/864/when-in-doubt-ask-for-a-citation

but probably should link to:
[FAQ: Must all questions be notable?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/864/when-in-doubt-ask-for-a-citation)

It's interesting that no one has noticed this issue before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks, I fixed the link.

It actually did link to the correct question (question `864`), just the title was wrong (the part in the URL after the ID, which is purely decorative). So when you clicked on it, you were redirected to the correct question at `https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/864/faq-must-all-questions-be-notable`, which might be why it wasn't noticed before. In either case, it wasn't correct, so thanks for noticing.

Comment: While you're editing things, can you fix the tour? "#What do I need to know?" should be a header but it uses the old markdown.

Comment: Thanks Tim.  Just FYI, I wasn't being redirected to the correct page.  I was getting a page with an invalid certificate.  Regardless, whatever you did fixed the issue, and it works now, so you have my thanks!

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket That error exists because of a switch from `https://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com` to `https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com` which happened a while ago. Most URLs were updated automatically, but some weren't. Odd that I didn't get the error. But all the better that the error was caught and fixed.

Comment: @Laurel Done, thanks!

Comment: @tim Do you know about when that order of the hosts were changed?  I didn't know about that change, so I might have some code to fix.  Also, did that change impact all of SE?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Apparently in 2017 (specifically [2017-03-16](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time/292602)).

Comment: @tim Thank you Tim.  I think my code was written after that date, which is probably why I haven't received any reports of issues.

Comment: @tim: To clarify, there were actually 2 separate changes in the URL format: one from `http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com` to `http://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com`, and then the shift from HTTP to HTTPS. Visiting `meta.skeptics` links now automatically redirects to the `skeptics.meta` format, and HTTP links automatically redirect to the HTTPS format. The invalid certificate error only appears if you try to go to `https://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com` specifically, since the HTTPS certificates are only for `*.stackexchange.com`.

Comment: See animuson's and Oded's answers to the MSE post [HTTPS certificate error for meta redirect pages (meta.<site>.stackexchange.com)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299086/335251), and animuson's answer to the MSE post [TLS for meta.*.stackexchange.com, again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372657/335251) (which reiterates Oded's answer to the previous post)