# War on terrible questions

Tags: discussion, questions, quality

When I read [Jeff's answer](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/806/how-notable-does-a-claim-have-to-be-for-questions-about-it-to-be-considered-on-to/808#808) to this question today I had a minor brain tremor and quickly pulled out my trigger happy down voting finger to relieve the rage.

Here's a quote:

> I think this site has too many questions, and specifically too many
>   low-quality and marginally on-topic questions at the moment.

With this at the back of my mind while I went about the site today I came to the conclusion that Jeff is right (6 hours later I can't undo my downvote, sorry mate).

I admit there has been an extra effort over the past week by Sklivz and Oddt to close some of the worst questions. I am suggesting that we all get out there and help with the house cleaning and start flagging and voting to close. It only takes 500 votes to close and this site has plenty of people in that category.

We also have 27 people with 2000+ rep who can view flags and also see what has been vote to close recently.

We can do some [CHAOS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100137/what-is-the-meaning-of-chaos-is-it-related-to-the-psi-character) work of our own and start improving our questions and make this site a repository of high quality questions and answers.

Comment: Full support from me, and I believe all mods.

Comment: I've always wanted to do this, but was scared of community reaction.

Comment: Isn't Sklivvz one of the persons with the terrible questions himself? :)

Answer (score 6):

Here is one thing that has helped on *parenting.SE:*

We recently (only last week!) edited *every* question's title and tags. We only had ~450 questions so it was manageable. Our goal was to make every question sound like a question ([see here: Why are the mods editing all the questions?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211/why-are-the-mods-editing-all-the-questions)). We also edited the worst question contents to improve their readability and formatting.

The result was a general appearance of higher quality, which helps shape how new askers act. Questions that were created after this "attack" were mostly of a higher quality.

This might work for *skeptics* too?

Comment: For more info check out some [comments](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1497775#1497775) from [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1541084#1541084) on the [subject](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1497619#1497619). (posted for Aarthi who's having technical difficulties)