# Isn't it a bad sign that this site requires 3 one-page FAQs just to explain what it is about?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I love the stackexchange network of websites, and use a lot of them to learn stuff. I have a problem with *skeptics*, though.

I'm having a hard time figuring what the site is really about. Some questions I ask are answered, others are closed within a few hours as being "off topic".

How come this is the only website with such a complicated answer to "what is off topic ?" :

- https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq
- [FAQ: Must all questions be notable?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/864/faq-must-all-questions-be-notable)
- [How notable does a claim have to be for questions about it to be considered on-topic?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/806/how-notable-does-a-claim-have-to-be-for-questions-about-it-to-be-considered-on-t)

"*it is for researching the evidence behind claims. It is not for (...) investigating original claims.*". Then what's a "good claim" ? I got [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4923/was-this-quote-about-unruly-kids-written-by-an-assyrian) answered with nothing more than "*I read in an email that ...*" !

Questions are closed with not much more explanation than "read the FAQ" (RTFM ?), and it's easy for a newbie like myself to feel discouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That [citation you mention](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4923/was-this-quote-about-unruly-kids-written-by-an-assyrian) is highly notable (a quick search with Google returns almost [40,000](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=%22Our+Earth+is+degenerate+in+these+later+days%22&meta=) hits). The whole point of notability is that we don't want people to "make stuff up" and pretend it's a claim.

This [other question of yours](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5295/is-it-possible-to-be-immunized-to-a-poison) is also about a well-known myth, see e.g. http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AcquiredPoisonImmunity

Finally, this other [question about lifeboats](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6924/is-it-true-that-no-ship-ever-sunk-for-having-too-many-life-boats): while the quote is notable, it looks like it's only intended metaphorically and not literally. In other words, it is *never* used in the context on planning how many lifeboats to include on a ship. On the other hand, the metaphorical sense isn't worth debating because it's so general: "One can never take enough precautions".

Comment: There were others that I deleted.

Comment: My question is "isn't it a bad thing that the aim of the site is so confusing for new users ?"

Comment: @Manu, it's a rethorical question. Of course it's not a good thing. However, maybe you could actually suggest improvements?

Comment: change the point of the site, have a tutorial with example questions, be nicer to new users.

Comment: @Manu "changing the point of the site" is not possible (at best, another site can be opened with a different scope); "have a tutorial": we try our best here in meta, we even have a "best questions of Skeptics" question etc. the info is all available already...; I don't think we are un-nice. Closing questions is not a big thing here on stack exchange sites: it only prevents answers until the question is fixed, and can be undone by the community with 5 votes. So don't take that as not being nice, it's how these sites work.

Comment: Great, there actually was an answer to my question : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SS_Eastland

Comment: Let's try answering questions next time, instead of closing them because you don't think they should be asked. :(

Comment: @Manu evidently you completely missed the point. Of course you can have too many life boats. This doesn't make your question appropriate here.

Comment: Yep, I did. Judging by the number of closed questions on the front page I'm not the only one.

Comment: Admit that it is frustrating : It was a valid claim, notable, with an answer from History. Yet it is closed because the claim can be understood metaphorically ?

Comment: @Manu: The only claim there is the one that *you* are making. *You* are deciding to take a common saying literally. There is no notability. Please try to accept my comment instead of insisting.